# Odds of getting four-of-a-kind three hands in a row

Tags: texas-hold-em, odds

What are the odds of this happening?

Texas Hold 'em.  7 Players.

Someone got 4 of a kind (8's) on a hand.  Pocket 8's and 2 on the board.

On the next hand, someone else got 4 of a kind, and it was 8's again.  1 8 in hand, 3 on board.

The next hand, someone got 4-of-a-kind - Kings.  Pocket Kings, 2 on board.

So, what are the odds of getting the same four-of-a-kind two hands in a row?

And then, getting another four-of-a-kind hand after that?

Comment: If this is a live game, hand shuffled deck, people eating hand held food strange bias can develop.

Comment: To answer this question requires some more information - for example whether we are to assume that anyone dealt a hand which could develop into the relevant quads will be played to showdown and a host of other variables which your question does not specify. Suffice to say, the chances of what you've described are very very **very** small and I would suggest you consider investigating the shuffling and dealing technique in this game.

Comment: I just had the same dude hit quads 2 hands in a row both times with a pocket pair. What are the odds of that happening?